# Can TypeScript infer which type was passed into a union type as a param?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a small utility function that removes a specified number of elements from a string or array. I'd like for the compiler to be able to infer whether the return value is a string or an array, based on what was passed to the function. Is there a way to do this?

```js
function shave<T>(iterable: string | T[], n: number) {
  return n > 0 ? iterable.slice(0, iterable.length - n) : iterable.slice(n * -1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript supports function overloads which allow specifying multiple type signatures for the same function.

Create overloads by putting these signatures before the function itself:

```js
function shave<T>(s: T[], n:number): T[]
function shave(s: string, n:number): string
function shave<T>(iterable: string | T[], n: number) {
  return n > 0 ? iterable.slice(0, iterable.length - n) : iterable.slice(n * -1)
}
```

With those overloads, the compiler infers the types you expect:

```js
const s = shave("abc", 2) // string
const a = shave([1,2,3], 2) // number[]
```

Comment: TIL TypeScript supports function overloads